how to adjust width,change back color and add icon image in dropdown textbox autocomplete in datagridview with VB.NET
Im Trying to adjust width based on length text,change back color and add icon image in dropdown textbox autocomplete in datagridview
for this adjust width based on length text >> Probably a column width solution in a DataGridView
Is it possible to apply?
Please Guide me
Thanks
Public Class Form4
    Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(
       sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles _
       DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox Then
            Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
            Dim tb = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)

            If dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
                If tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count = 0 Then
                    tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
                    tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(New String() {"Absecon", "Abstracta", "Abundantia", "Academia", "Acadiau", "Acamas", "Ackerman", "Ackley", "Ackworth", "Acomita", "Aconcagua", "Acton", "Acushnet", "Acworth", "Ada", "Ada", "Adair", "Adairs", "Adair", "Adak", "Adalberta", "Adamkrafft", "Adams"})
                End If
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
            Else
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class



update code based on answer from @dr.null from link
The problem is at the time I typed the Dropdown did not appear in the DatagridView combobox what might be wrong with my code and how can I use this font ☑️ so that it can appear in the combobox
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Dapper

Public Class Comboboxdgvautocomplete
    Private dictProducts As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)

        dictProducts = ProductFinalService.GetDistinctProducts().
            ToDictionary(Function(p) p.ProductName, Function(p) p.Unit)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ProductFinal)
        DataGridView1.Columns("Unit").ReadOnly = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles _
        DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        If TypeOf e.Control Is ComboBox Then
            Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
            Dim tb = DirectCast(e.Control, ComboBox)         
            If dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
                If tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count = 0 Then
                    tb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
                    tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
                    tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(dictProducts.Keys.ToArray())
                End If
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
            Else
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
        Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index AndAlso
           e.RowIndex <> dgv.NewRowIndex Then
            Dim key = e.FormattedValue?.ToString()

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) OrElse
               Not dictProducts.ContainsKey(key) Then
                Dim boundItem = DirectCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinal)

                boundItem.Unit = Nothing
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Invalid Product!"
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidated(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidated
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            Dim boundItem = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinal)
            If boundItem IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim value = dictProducts(boundItem.ProductName)
                If value <> boundItem.Unit Then
                    boundItem.Unit = value
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                End If
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        Dim src = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, BindingList(Of ProductFinal))
        If src.Count = e.RowIndex Then Return
        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText) Then
                Dim boundItem = DirectCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinal)
                Dim unit As String = Nothing

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(boundItem.Unit) AndAlso
                   dictProducts.TryGetValue(boundItem.ProductName, unit) Then
                    boundItem.Unit = unit
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim ProductFinalService As New ProductFinalService()
            Dim displayList = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, BindingList(Of ProductFinal))
            Dim outputList = displayList.
            Select(Function(p) New ProductFinal With {
            .ProductName = dictProducts(p.ProductName),
            .Unit = p.Unit
        })
            ProductFinalService.InsertProducts(CType(outputList, ProductFinal))
            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Successfull")
        Catch err As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Me, err.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub


End Class

Public Class ProductFinalService
    Private Shared Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                    Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test03092024option1.accdb;
                    Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function

    ' ...

    Friend Shared Function GetDistinctProducts() As IEnumerable(Of ProductFinal)
        Dim sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductName, Unit 
                       FROM Products 
                       ORDER BY ProductName"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ProductFinal)(sql)
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Sub InsertProducts(ByVal Obj As ProductFinal)
        Dim sql = $"INSERT INTO `saveproducts` (`ProductName`,`Unit`) VALUES ('{Obj.ProductName}','{Obj.Unit}');"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ProductFinal
    '<Browsable(False)>
    'Public Property Font As String = "☑️"

    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property Unit As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{ProductName} {Unit}"
    End Function

End Class


https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365974/Autocomplete-Menu

@dr.null , Thanks for the recommendation link, so I think it's better to use textbox and also already have updated the code in the post maybe you can help. I used the answer code from you in the previous post

@dr.null , for better icons I use fonts and the problem is that I have to resize manually in the dropdown ,so Can it be done automatically? and possible can I change the background color dropdown so that the color of the font (Checklist) becomes clearer color and one more I have to copy paste the font (Checklist) first to do autocomplete can I directly bypass directly typing the letters from the productname?

No way to format the autocomplete list. You can use instead custom combobox column and owner draw the dropdown list. Or create your own dropdown list and draw it as you wish. Btw, you don't need to add the Font property in your model. Include that check mark glyph in the ToString method override return. Btw2, if you don't want to display model property in the grid, just decorate it with the <Browsable(False)> attribute.

@dr.null , I have updated the code in the post as per your recommendation custom combobox but the autocomplete list does not appear. Please Guide me

@dr.null , I've updated the code in the post , The problem is that I can't type from the textbox if I can type then it makes it easier to search and selected in the mainlistbox (listbox) and how can I use this font ☑️ so that it can appear in the mainlistbox (listbox) . Please Guide me

In the EditingControlShowing event, set the combobox DropDownStyle to ComboBoxStyle.DropDown.

For the combobox, fill it's Items with the products and set it's AutoCompleteSource property to AutoCompleteSource.ListItems value.

@dr.null , thanks for your response , in the EditingControlShowing event, set the combobox DropDownStyle to ComboBoxStyle.DropDown.You mean I'm using the Control ComboBox of the DatagridView column

Yes. You're keep changing the question and posting different problems. Nobody can help you this way. All the comments and recommendations become irrelevant. You should focus on one problem per question to get focused responses and solutions.

@dr.null , ok I updated the question post only related to the textbox and combobox and to related to the listbox then I posted a new question

@dr.null , I have updated the code according to your recommendation but on me type dropdown combobox does not appear is there anything wrong with my code, please guide me
